# Find the determinants of the linear transformation as a function.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations, determinant

T(f(t)) = f(3t − 2) from P2 to P2

I know that I need to send the standard basis vectors corresponding to a 2 degree polynomial through the linear transformation but I can't figure it out since there is only one variable.

Comment: Hint: what is $T(t)$ and $T(t^2)$? This tells you how to build the matrix of linear transformation.

Comment: hmm thank you for the hint! could you perhaps explain how this relates to applying the transformation on the standard basis vectors?

Comment: Any polynomial in $P_2$ takes the form $f(t) = a + bt + ct^2.$ This is a linear combination of the standard basis elements. Now use the fact that $T$ is linear.

Comment: This is very very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_2$ be the vector space of all the polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ of degree not exceeding $2$ together with the zero polynomial, and let $T \colon P_2 \longrightarrow P_2$ be defined by
$$
(T f)(t) \colon= f(3t-2).
$$

We now find the matrix of this linear transformation with respect to the standard (ordered) basis for $P_2$, which consists of the ordered triple $\left( f_0, f_1, f_2 \right)$ of polynomials defined by $f_0(x) = 1$, $f_1(x) = x$, and $f_2(x) = x^2$.

We note that
$$
\begin{align} 
\left( T f_0 \right)(t) &= f_0(3t-2) = 1, \\
\left( T f_1 \right)(t) &= f_1(3t-2) =  3t-2 = -2 + 3t, \\
\left( T f_2 \right)(t) &= f_2(3t-2) = (3t-2)^2 = 9t^2 -12t + 4 = 4 - 12t + 9t^2.
\end{align}
$$

Thus we find that
$$
\begin{align}
T f_0 &= 1 f_0 + 0 f_1 + 0 f_2, \\
T f_1 &= -2 f_0 + 3 f_1 + 0 f_2, \\
T f_2 &= 4 f_0 - 12 f_1 + 9 f_2. 
\end{align}
$$

So the matrix of $T$ is given by
$$
[T] = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & -2 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 & -12  \\ 0 & 0 & 9  \end{matrix} \right]. 
$$